# java.io.IOException: Premature EOF when reading Transfer-Encoding: chunked http response

Tags: java, http, http-headers

I've written a small command line program to read web pages and print the response body out to the terminal.

This works well for most sites, however when reading a chunked response from this url: http://www.pampers.co.uk/home I get the following back trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:538)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:582)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:669)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2668)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
at HttpPageReader.main(HttpPageReader.java:44)`
```

I've hardcoded the charset to match the response from this page. What steps should I take to debug this issue? I'm assuming this isn't a Java bug but an issue with what's returned by the web server - however I have viewed the page in my web browser and also downloaded it using curl, both without problem.

The code is as follows, should be easy to copy and paste and run stand alone:

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class HttpPageReader
{    
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HttpPageReader.class.getName());

private static final int SECOND_IN_MILLI_SECONDS = 1000;
private static final int TIME_OUT_MILLI_SECONDS  = 10 * SECOND_IN_MILLI_SECONDS;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if ( args.length != 1)
    {
        logger.warning("Please provide a url to download");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    logger.info("Downloading url " + args[0] + "...");

    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(args[0]);

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "My User Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        httpConn.setConnectTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLI_SECONDS);
        httpConn.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLI_SECONDS);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpConn.getInputStream(), "utf-8");                        
        char chars[] = new char[1000];
        int numRead = inputStreamReader.read(chars);
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (numRead != -1)
        {
            stringBuffer.append(new String(chars, 0, numRead));
            numRead = inputStreamReader.read(chars);
        }

        logger.info("done");            
        logger.info(stringBuffer.toString());

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}   
}
```

Update: Using IOUtils.toString(httpConn.getInputStream(), "utf-8") as suggested gives pretty much the same backtrace - so the question remains, how do I go about debugging this problem?

Gives:

```
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:538)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:582)
at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:669)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2668)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:123)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1928)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1907)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1884)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1834)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:705)
at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:730)
at HttpPageReader.main(HttpPageReader.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..... this way its easier... And remember dont overload the program with n nos things until u really need them......

Just Copy paste this code and try out...then try to modify it in your own way.... best of luck  !!!

```
package com.my;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSrc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://www.pampers.co.uk/home");
            try {
                InputStream i = url.openStream();
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(i);

                while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                    System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question here is really about how to debug this issue. This solution, whilst it doesn't seem to cause the same exception to be thrown, still doesn't print all the HTML that's returned - it prints exactly the same amount as my code does. Looking at the response in either a web browser or Wireshark you can see the response finishes with a closing html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `IOUtils.toString(inputStream)` ?

[Apache Commons IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/)

Comment: also `IOUtils.toString(inputStream, charset)`

Comment: Just tried it, get pretty much the same back trace. Will update the question with the details.